# Required field validator text positioning

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css

I have problem getting my text from the validation under my textbox. It show up behind my textbox, just like in picture.

[image: textboxvalidationmissplace]

In my code for the type of assignment and assignment start textbox i have a css-class setting saying that display = block. That put the validation text under the textbox. If i put that on this element my second textbox end up under the first one (for example, the big empty textbox after the textbox saying AC- end up under the textbox saying AC-). I tried all different solutions but maybe I'm staring myself blind on the problem. I will pust my current code and i hope anyone out there can help me fix this problem.

first my aspx...

```
    <div class="floatLeftPaddTop15PaddLeft40">
        <asp:Label id="costCodesLabel2" runat="server" >Cost code 2:</asp:Label><br />
        <asp:TextBox id="costCodeTextBox2Prefix" runat="server" CssClass="textBoxPrefix" Visible="false" ></asp:TextBox>
        <div class="costCodeDiv" >
            <asp:TextBox id="costCodeTextBox2" runat="server" CssClass="textBoxSuffix" ></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="costCodeValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="costCodeTextBox2" ErrorMessage="Cost code is required."
                ForeColor="Red"  Display="Dynamic" Enabled="false" />
        </div>    
    </div>
```

then my css...

```
.textBoxSuffix {
    width: 120px;
    height: 22px;
    border: 1px solid #999; 
}.

.textBoxPrefix {
   width: 35px;
   height: 22px;
   border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

Comment: put a `br/>` tag after the textbox

Comment: Omg, of course. Dont put my validation text exatly where i want it thought but close enough... it start at the leftmost of the AC- textbox

Comment: Then give `margin-left` to the element

Comment: That did it, thank you both for quick repsonse! :)

Answer (score -1):

Or you can build the page with a html table ...